# It is possible for my Rails App knows under which context of HTTP is running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, rack

In certain situations I run my app in a context like: /context/app , but sometimes I only use: /app

In my DB I have an applications table that has an attribute for the path of the application (ex. /app ), what I'm looking is that my app could determine in which context is running in order to update that attribute (ex. /context/app)

I think is a rack thing but I don't know how can I ask him for that information.

The context is set through passenger using RailsBaseURI.

Comment: I think you can find the original uri in the request object (you can access it in your controllers) http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActionController/Request.html#M001995. If you get the uri, you get the context if i understood well

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
RAILS_ROOT
```

give you what you need? It should return the root of the application.

If this isn't what you are after then I think more information is needed about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Oliver but RAILS_ROOT does not solve my problem since RAILS_ROOT works in File System level and what I need is something that inspect the context in an url.